# How to prevent submit the form on click in blank rich:autocomplete component?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, autocomplete, richfaces

I am implementing rich :autocomplete component in my project. 
My problem is that when i am going to click on blank autocomplete component that time my form is submitted.
I don't get it why my code going to submit the form on blank autocomplete click? 
my autocomplete code

```
<rich:autocomplete  mode="ajax" minChars="3" autofill="false"
                        autocompleteMethod="#{bean.autocompletePersonName}" layout="div" var="var"
                        fetchValue="#{var.employeeCode}" onselectitem="addPersonName(this.value)">  
                            <rich:column> #{bean.employeeCode} </rich:column>
                    </rich:autocomplete>
```

my buttons.

```
 <h:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="save" action="#{beans.methodA}" />
  <h:commandButton id="cancelBtn"  value="cancel" onclick="window.location ='#{request.contextPath}/page/page'" />
```

When i am going to click on blank autocomplete component that time the action is performed on save button means call the methodA method

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue, what version of RichFaces do you use? Also `#{bean.employeeCode}` should be `#{var.employeeCode}`.

Comment: I our project we are using 3.4.5 version. When I going click on blank autocomplete that time page is submitted.Means it calls methodA method

Comment: As I said, I can't replicate it. You can try using `<a4j:log>` to find out what is happening, it might be something else executing the entire form.